# Update a view with realtime data that is not presented yet, ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am unclear on how to handle the following scenario…

Assume that you are generating some data in viewcontroller A, for example, performing audio recording in real time. And you have a viewcontroller B which will be presented by A when you press a button. What viewcontroller B does is display audio data in a graph. Viewcontroller B is constantly updated as audio recording goes on no matter when it's presented or before its view is loaded to the screen.

It's my requirement that whenever user press the button to show the data graph, the graph must contain historical data and keeping updating as well. The user can also go back and forth between the two viewcontrollers during the recording to stop recording (in A) or inspect the data graph (in B).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try setting a property on the first (A) view controller and passing it into your second (B) view controller.

FirstViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *data;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)generateAudioData
{
    self.data = // Your audio data generating code goes here perhaps?
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

SecondViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

SecondViewController.m:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *graphData;

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FirstViewController *audioData = (FirstViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.graphData = audioData.data;
    // Create your graph UIView here and populate it with self.graphData
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you don't store data in view controllers.  Create a "model" layer (object or group of objects) that stores the information that you need to display.  When a view controller's view appears or needs refreshing, get data from the model.  That way you don't have to do anything complicated concerning the state of a controller; it takes responsibility for getting what it needs at the right time.